# from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt returns ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

Under Windows 11 I just upgraded to python 3.12.0
I also installed PyQt6

So this is a up-to-date setup

I have located the DDL in
C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\bin\Qt6Core.dll

I of course have in the path C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\

I even added

C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts;
C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\PyQt6\Qt6\bin;

But that didn't make a difference.

> python --version
> Python 3.12.0

> pip show PyQt6
> Name: PyQt6
> Version: 6.6.0
> Summary: Python bindings for the Qt cross platform application toolkit
> Home-page: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
> Author: Riverbank Computing Limited
> Author-email: info@riverbankcomputing.com
> License: GPL v3
> Location: C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> Requires: PyQt6-Qt6, PyQt6-sip
> Required-by:

Any idea ?

I upgraded to  3,12,0 because I had the same issue with 3.10

Comment: how did you do the install?   `python -m pip install PyQt6` ?

Comment: I had the same issue on W10 for the last couple of days (despite trying fresh installs of Python, pip, and venv), but it seems a new install just now got the most recent version of PyQt6-6.6.1 instead of 6.6.0 and it just works (user install without venv). Or it could be that it's because I installed Qt Creator (hoping that any missing DLL then would become available). PyQt5 worked though. Good luck!